# How should one learn the minchas chinuch

Tags: torah-study

I recently purchased the Sefer and I would like to know how others have gone through it. What are the darchei limud? How can it be approached as a stand-alone Sefer? Any tip?

Comment: Please indicate why this book is different?

Comment: It's mainly based on chiluk, short development. As all works, you need to read a lot to grasp his way and afterwards to learn it slowly